# Rails video tag sound won't turn off when changing pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a video tag for the first time and the video has music the problem is that when you go the the next page the music continues. I can't seem to find anything on how to stop it.

Here is my tag:

```
<%= video_tag "propose.mp4", autoplay: :autoplay, loop: :loop, mute: :mute, class: "video" %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that it's related to Turbolinks caching. Does disabling Turbolinks help?

Comment: Looks like removing Turbolinks did work.

Answer (score 0):

This actually seems to be a problem with the HTML5 video tag. I'd recommend intercepting your page changes (with jQuery for example) and then pausing the video with JavaScript. I'm assuming you're using jQuery:

Like this:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
  $(".video").removeFromParent();
});
```

If this doesn't work, you should try to pause the video instead of removing it from its parent, but I think this should work. Give it a try :)

Cheers